# how to convert uml2 file (*.uml) to xmi file?

Tags: xml, uml, xmi

I created a .uml file by Eclipse uml2 tools,
but how can I convert the .uml file to .xmi file so that I can import the .xmi file to other uml case tool.

should I convert .uml to .ecore(EMF model), and then use org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.util.XMLProcessor.save() to save as xmi file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The .uml file is the model and is already a xmi file. The problem is that you create one model per diagram and therefore how to consolidate all these models.
It is impossible to import EclipseUML2 tools into another tool if you don't first use a kind of model mapper which would find the logic which is dispatched among all this models.

Only one tool have developped a  model merger for EclipseUML2 tool because EclipseUML tool project had been stopped since Eclipse 3.5. Omondo allows you to merge many models into a single model and then reuse this single model into any other UML 2.x compatible tool.

Comment: Thanks, GURU.  but can *.uml be imported directly by other uml case tool? I thought *.xmi is the common standard file can imported by uml case tool.

Answer (score 0):

The extension of the file does not really matter. It already is xmi in there. I.e. Enterprise Architect, Rational Software Architect or UML Lab can import it or open it directly.

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I just installed EA trival, it seems EA can import .xsd exported by .uml.  But it seems EA can not import/open .uml file directly.

Comment: Did you try this one? http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/projects_and_teams/importxmi.html

Comment: Thanks again, Christian. I found import xmi, import emx/uml2 in EA user guide from the link you posted.  But emx/uml2 is models of RSA, if I want to import .uml file created by EMF&UML2, I still think I should convert .uml file to .xmi file, shouldn't I?

Comment: RSA uses 99,9% the same libraries and file format, so it's essentially the same regarding import of the model (only diagram positions etc. are stored differently)